# My solution for Leetcode problem produces result in debug area but giving complie error in submission page

Tags: java, algorithm

I created a solution for the problem (minimum size subarray sum)in leetcode and its running in my laptop even in leetcode debug area(producing result), but giving compile error in submission page. Could anyone please let me know whats is causing this compile error and resolution for this?

Below is the compile error I am getting:(highlighted the Line no:10,even line 10 doesn't seems to be related to this error)

Line 10: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Integer[] [in **Driver**.java]

```
class Solution {
    static int size=0;
    static int wsize=0;
    static int indic =0;
    public static int minSubArrayLen(Integer[] arr, int res){
        int st=0;
    for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            int a=arr[j];
            if(a==6){
    (Line no:10)    size=1;
            indic =1;
            return size;
            }
            st=st+arr[j];
            if(st==res){
                wsize=j+1;
                break;
            }
            if(st>6){
                wsize= j;
                break;
            }

        } return wsize;
    }

    public static int compare(int wsize, Integer[] arr,int res){
        int ans=0;
        for(int i =1;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==res){
                size=1;
                return size;
            }
            wsize= (wsize-1)+i;
            for(int k=i;k<wsize-1;k++){
                ans=ans+arr[k];
                if(ans>res){
                    break;
                }
                if(res==6){
                    size=(k+1)-i;
                }
            }

        }
        return size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Integer[] arr = {1,5,7,9,-2,6,3,9};
        Integer[] arr = {1,5,7,9,-2,3,9};
        int res=6;
        size=minSubArrayLen(arr, res);
        if(size!=0 && indic==0){
            size=compare(size,arr,res);
        }
        System.out.println(size);


    }

}
```

Comment: That’s not Driver.java, that’s Solution.java

Comment: yeah, its displaying Driver.java instead of Solution.java, no idea why.(even line number 10 seems not related to compile error).I cannot validate my answer so.